# Idiomatic JSON object array -> map[string]json.RawMessage

Tags: json, http, go

I am trying to unmarshal the results of an HTTP REST API request that, depending on the number of results, returns **either an object or an array of objects**.

Requests are generic because I'm trying to build a wrapper around a specific REST API and it's called like:

```golang
// Function prototype where I am trying to convert the response
func (client *Client) Get(endpoint string, data map[string]string) (map[string]json.RawMessage, error)

// The way the function is called
client.Get("/v1/users", map[string]string{"filter.abc": "lorem ipsum"})
```

Two examples of response:

```
[
  {
    "abc": "def",
    "efg": 123
    "hij": [
      {
        "klm": "nop"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "abc": "def",
    "efg": 123
    "hij": [
      {
        "klm": "nop"
      }
    ]
  }
]
// RESPONSE 1: Array of JSON objects that have child arrays

{
  "abc": "def",
  "efg": 123
  "hij": [
    {
      "klm": "nop"
    }
  ]
}
// RESPONSE 2: In this case, only one element was returned.
```

I've achieved to do this for only the response 2 with something like this:

```golang
// [...]
byteBody = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
// [...]
var body map[string]json.RawMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal(byteBody, &body); err != nil { [...] }
```

So, what's the most idiomatic way of parsing this? Is there any way to avoid writing redundant code and parse both responses? I was thinking in giving as an additional parameter the "model" the response should be put into. Is it a good practice? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: well, as API designer I'd prefer to return always the same structure in the response (aka always an array of items). do you have power to change it? IMHO it will make the server and the client simpler

Comment: I am not, unluckily. I am only the consumer of the API, not the designer or developer. I totally agree that it being consistent would be great, however it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure is idiomatic but this code could be an [example](https://go.dev/play/p/HOzQkbVVmsA).

In short you can try to unmarshal in one format and, if it fails, in the other one

the key function is

```golang
func parseStr(data string) ([]Item, error) {
    item := Item{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &item); err == nil {
        return []Item{item}, nil
    }

    items := []Item{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &items); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid JSON data")
    }
    return items, nil

}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for opening up this again. I have been implementing this solution now. Is there any way to apply this solution to a wider set of models? Not only Item but any "interface". Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarioMartínMoreno The second example in my answer shows how to work with arbitrary models.  It shouldn't be difficult to adapt that code to this answer (or just use the code in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Examine the first non-whitespace byte in the JSON document to determine if the document is an array or object.

```
func decodeArrayOrObject(doc []byte) ([]map[string]json.RawMessage, error) {
    trimmedDoc := bytes.TrimSpace(doc)
    switch {
    case len(trimmedDoc) == 0:
        return nil, errors.New("empty body")
    case trimmedDoc[0] == '{':
        var m map[string]json.RawMessage
        err := json.Unmarshal(doc, &m)
        return []map[string]json.RawMessage{m}, err
    case trimmedDoc[0] == '[':
        var s []map[string]json.RawMessage
        err := json.Unmarshal(doc, &s)
        return s, err
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("unexpected type")
    }
}
```

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to create a function that works with arbitrary slice types:

```
func decodeArrayOrObject(doc []byte, slicep interface{}) error {
    trimmedDoc := bytes.TrimSpace(doc)
    switch {
    case len(trimmedDoc) == 0:
        return errors.New("empty document")
    case trimmedDoc[0] == '[':
        return json.Unmarshal(doc, slicep)
    case trimmedDoc[0] == '{':
        s := reflect.ValueOf(slicep).Elem()
        s.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(s.Type(), 1, 1))
        return json.Unmarshal(doc, s.Index(0).Addr().Interface())
    default:
        return errors.New("unexpected type")
    }
}
```

Call the function with a pointer to a slice of structs or a pointer to a slice of struct pointers.

```
var v []Example
err := decodeArrayOrObject(body, &v)
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_sX95QgdajT).